# Yii1 - CDataProviderIterator limit doesn't work

Tags: yii, yii1.x

I am using `criteria` and `CActiveDataProvider` to make the query, and then I want to use `CDataProviderIterator`, but it seems that `CDataProviderIterator` is ignoring the limit.

The code so far:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->select    = "t.id";
$criteria->join      = 'LEFT JOIN purged_files ON t.id = purged_files.project_id';
$criteria->order     = "t.id asc";
$criteria->condition = " purged_files.id IS NULL AND `new_status_id` IN ('DELIVERED', 'PAID') AND `created` <= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 180 DAY)";
$criteria->limit     = 1;
$criteria->offset    = 0;
$criteria->together  = true;

$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Project', array(
    'criteria'   => $criteria,
    'pagination' => false
));

$iterator = new CDataProviderIterator($dataProvider);
```

What seems to be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot disable pagination and use `CDataProviderIterator` at the same time. If you look into source of `CDataProviderIterator` you will see that it [always use pagination](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/ff081d764e9d0c67c06de52754a1d82b481cac42/framework/web/CDataProviderIterator.php#L53-L54). That is purpose of this class - it uses pagination to avoid loading millions of records into memory at the same time. If your limit is low and loading all data into memory will not exceed some memory limits, you probably don't need to use `CDataProviderIterator` at all - you can fetch data directly from data provider:

```
foreach ($dataProvider->getData() as $project) {
    $project->doSomething();
}
```

Or do not use data provider at all:

```
$models = Project::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

If your really need a `CDataProviderIterator`, you may set limit by using `totalItemsCount` property to override real number of records:

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Project', array(
    'criteria'   => $criteria,
    'totalItemsCount' => 5000,
));
```

Make sure that your `totalItemsCount` is not lower than actual number of records. You may want to query database to calculate this value.